# Двоеточие после слова "вопрос"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно:

> Письменно ответьте на вопрос: "Как я провел лето".

Или

> Письменно ответьте на вопрос "Как я провел лето".

В интернете видела оба варианта написания.

Comment: Если в предложении есть фраза "ответьте на вопрос", то обязательно - хоть где-нибудь - должен быть знак вопроса. Иначе: в чем смысл вопросительного предложения - без знака вопроса?

Comment: Я расскажу вам, как я провел лето.  Человек не может спросить у себя: "Как я провел лето?"  Здесь КАК - относительное, а не вопросительное местоимение. А "вопрос" в данном случае синонимичен "теме". Напишите сочинение на тему: "Как я провел лето".

Comment: Но человеку предлагают именно вопросом задаться, подумать и ответить на него в форме сочинения - это "ответ" от него ожидается в повествовательной форме. Если бы ему на одноимённую "тему" предложили написать, тогда предложении фигурировал бы "ответ" (/вот/ как я провёл...), поэтому "тема" не является здесь синонимом "вопроса". В "тему" вопрос можно перевести лишь переходом к косвенной речи.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны разные варианты:

**Вариант 1.** Письменно ответьте на (следующий) вопрос: "Как я провел лето".

Здесь значение **пояснения**, двоеточие обозначает предупредительную паузу.

**Вариант 2.** На уроке мы письменно отвечали   на вопрос "Как я провел лето". Это **несогласованное определение**, нет двоеточия и паузы.

У Розенталя на эту тему: [§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

Comment: Если вы оставляете кавычки, то это цитата (или прямая речь). Можно ли говорить о цитате как о пояснении и дополнении и выводить наличие двоеточия из этого?

Comment: У Розенталя: "Пояснительным может быть не только член предложения, но и целое предложение". НАЗВАНИЕ вопроса или темы, заключенное в кавычки,  также может выполнять функцию определения или пояснения по отношению к определяемому слову (тема, вопрос).

Answer (score 1):

*Мария Петрова:*

> Письменно ответьте на вопрос: "Как я провел лето?"
>
> или
>
> Письменно ответьте на вопрос "Как я провел лето?".

По-моему, оба варианта неправильны.

Более-менее правильным при сохранении первой части предложения будет такой вариант (с заменой "я" на "вы"):

***Письменно ответьте на вопрос, как вы провели лето.***

Comment: Интересное замечание. И в самом деле, вопрос содержит "я", то есть обращен к самому себе, а ответить нужно учителю - замысловато и не очень корректно получается. "Как я провел лето" - подходит как заголовок рассказа. Тут можно порассуждать на тему, должен ли такой заголовок заканчиваться знаком вопроса. Я бы такой знак не ставил, но не берусь агрументированно объяснить почему.

Comment: Но если заменить "я" на "ты", то возвращемся в исходную точку (к вопросу Марии): так нужно ставить двоеточие или нет? **Письменно ответьте на вопрос(:) "Как ты провел лето?".**

Comment: А почему "не очень корректно"? Учитель предлагает ученику письменно ответить на конкретный вопрос, который тот должен _поставить перед собой_; форма ответа - за учеником. Не вижу ничего плохого в первом варианте.